# Using AI to learn Japanese

Tags: discussion, kanji

I've been using ChatGPT to learn Japanese specifically in getting vocab. My prompt is:

```
Always answer in this format for Japanese Word

Kanji(furigana)
JLPT level:
Commonness:
Formality:
Usually written in hiragana/katakana or kanji:
Each of the kanji meaning:

Word meaning and explanation

3 example with why it is used/explanation in the example

Summary of all above
```

I'm curious if anyone did it like me. Is there any improvement/tips that I can use on my prompt?

Comment: This is off-topic on the primary site, but is probably fine for the meta site, however I think most people here will tell you that any information you get from ChatGPT should not be trusted. It will just make things up that sound plausible. There are lots of resources that can be trusted that can be found on the meta site as well.

Comment: @Leebo, I second your opinion that info got from ChatGPT should not be trusted. However, you can leverage it in other ways to enhance your learning. For example, to play Kanji chain games.

Comment: Always remember, *you* are the teacher with AI. Using it to teach you is a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I believe it's entirely possible to learn using AI, but this is only true in areas where AI really excels. For instance, I find it completely feasible to learn Python programming or PostgreSQL through ChatGPT. Personally, I rely heavily on ChatGPT when I need to learn the nuances of English words I'm not familiar with, or when I want to have my English text proofread.

However, **at this point, I wouldn't recommend using ChatGPT to learn kanji**. Currently, ChatGPT often makes terrible errors about the basic readings of kanji. It also struggles with explaining grammar concepts or their JLPT levels. Simply, ChatGPT's knowledge is far from sufficient in these fields. The type of information you are looking for should be looked up in a regular dictionary, not through AI.

That said, when given the right context, ChatGPT can be helpful for tasks such as translating Japanese sentences into English or clarifying the meanings of common slang terms.

Comment: as long as you double check your results when asking about Python or PostgreSQL, it's a good tool. However, ChatGPT is also known to produce *code* output that *looks* good but is faulty.

Comment: At least with code, you can actually check to see if it does what you wanted. I could imagine inefficiencies or unforeseen bugs cropping up as well, but it's at least a bit more plausible that you can just use what it gives you without consulting something else.

Comment: I once had ChatGPT tell me straight in the face that 亻 is the simplified character of 人...

Comment: @dvx2718 Was it about kanji radicals? Then ChatGPT is correct. にんべん is a form of 人.

Comment: @naruto no it was about Kanji simplification. Clearly 人 is never simplified and has no 新字体